# Application pool error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7

Am getting this error on my IIS 7 application server.

*"A process serving application pool '%1' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service"*

How do i resolve this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like the IIS worker process is crashing. If you have multiple sites/applications running on the same AppPool, I'd start by isolating them one at a time into separate AppPools. You'll probably find which one is causing the problem that way, which should give you a place to start looking.

Aside from this, I'd guess I'd take a look at using adplus to get a crash dump of the AppPool process and then run through it in WinDBG to see what comes up. There are some good resources for this out there. Two that should help you get started are [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954594.aspx) and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892277). They are a bit outdated but the basic mechanics should still be mostly the same.